# how to deny login access to certain users in AWS Cognito

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a web-application which uses AWS cognito for login purposes. There are two divisions, Managers and employee. I don't want employee to be able to login through the manager login page. Currently I only have one user pool with 3 users which are able to login through both manager and employee login page. Is there anything I can do to prevent that?

code for manager login page is this. Employee login page is almost similar to this:

````
import './App.css';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import { AmplifyAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { AuthState, onAuthUIStateChange } from '@aws-amplify/ui-components';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

const AuthStateApp = () => {
    const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState();
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        return onAuthUIStateChange((nextAuthState, authData) => {
            setAuthState(nextAuthState);
            setUser(authData)
        });
    }, []);

  return authState === AuthState.SignedIn && user ? (
      <div className="App">
          <div>Hello, {user.username}</div>
          <AmplifySignOut />
      </div>
    ) : (
          <AmplifyAuthenticator />
        );
    }

export default AuthStateApp;```
````

Comment: See [Token Claims to Use in Rule-Based Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html#token-claims-for-role-based-access-control).